# ACL NAT'ing on Cisco ASA 9.2

Tags: nat, cisco-asa

I'm trying to implement (P)NAT on a active/standby pair of 5525X running v9.2

I need to NAT an ACL not an object and I've been unable to work out how to do this.  The ACL is

`access-list 3G_traffic extended deny host 192.168.0.1 192.168.31.0 255.255.255.0
access-list 3G_traffic extended deny 192.168.31.0 255.255.255.0 host 192.168.0.1
access-list 3G_traffic extended permit any 192.168.31.0 255.255.255.0`

So to summarise, all traffic to 192.168.31.0/24 should be NAT'd except for traffic to/from 192.168.0.1.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution:

`sysopt noproxyarp outside2
!
object network net_192.168.31.0
 subnet 192.168.31.0 255.255.255.0
!
object network net_192.168.1.0
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
!
object network net_192.168.2.0
 subnet 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
!
object-group network 3G_NAT
 network-object object net_192.168.1.0
 network-object object net_192.168.2.0
!
nat (any,outside2) source dynamic 3G_NAT interface destination static net_192.168.31.0 net_192.168.31.0`

There's a lot of route changes as well.

I also noticed that when the NAT is implemented, any running pings didn't reflect the change for about 2-3 minutes.  New pings immediately worked.  This caught me out ...

Hope this helps someone.